# Junit testing DAO layer with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit

I try to test simple class:

```
public class GenericDAO {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public <T> Serializable create(final T o) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(o);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T find(final Class<T> cl, final long id) {
        return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(cl, id);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T update(final T o) {
        return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(o);
    }

    public <T> void delete(final T o) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(o);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> List<T> getAll(final Class<T> cl) {
        return (List<T>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(cl).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
    }
}
```

In my test class I use @Before to create session and fill database for testing, something like this:

```
    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;    

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(user);
        session.save(user1);
        session.save(user2);
        session.flush();
        // Otherwise the query returns the existing order 
        session.clear();
    }
```

As for me it is better to use @BeforeClass to fill db, because I need to create test date only once at the begining of class. But this method must be static so I cannot autowired sessionFactory. So what is the best solution for this?

Comment: What are you testing here? That hibernate works? That spring works? I wouldn't bother. Break out the "do it" code from the "glue" code and test that

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this problem is to implement `DataSource` in such a way that it forwards all method calls to the real data source.

When a connection is requested from my `DataSource`, I check if that's the first connection (just a boolean flag). If it is, I set up the database before I return the connection.

Pseudocode:

```
getConnection() {
    conn = delegate.getConnection()
    if( firstConnection ) {
        firstConnection = false;
        setupDatabase( conn );
    }
    return conn;
}
```

That also makes the DB setup lazy.

Note: Your code tests a lot of things that you shouldn't: Hibernate, JDBC, the DB driver, the database. Generally, you should assume that these pieces work or are tested by someone else.

For most tests, it should be sufficient to [mock the `GenericDAO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).

Comment: So I don't need to write test for such simple method, do I? And how about "getAll(...)" method? It has some logic. So is it better to use  Mock object in this case?

Comment: Always ask: "Why do I want to know?" It might make sense to write *one* unit test to make sure `getAll()` itself works (`testGetAll()`) but you probably don't want to set up a database every time one of your tests *uses* `getAll()` (i.e. tests which test code eventually that calls `getAll()`).